# Docker, Unable to install GIT in Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I Created a container and tried to install GIT in the container through Dockerfile.

Appreciate your comments.

Tried to install GIT with Dockerfile, Error

### => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
=> => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
=> CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                                                                   0.0s
=> ERROR [2/2] RUN yum install git -y                                                                                                                                                  0.5s

> [2/2] RUN yum install git -y:
> 0.294 /bin/sh: 1: yum: not found

---

### Dockerfile:2

1 |     FROM ubuntu
2 | >>> RUN yum install git -y

Comment: ubuntu doesnt have `yum` package manager. have you tried with `apt-get`?

Comment: (For many uses you'll find it better to run Git and other source-control tool outside the container; consider adding the `Dockerfile` to the repository.  There are tricky questions about credentials to private repositories, what commit exactly you're checking out, and using Docker's layer cache that are much easier to deal with if your Dockerfile doesn't try to invoke source control on its own.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like this in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
```

If you want to use 'yum' you should use [centos](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos) or [radhat](https://hub.docker.com/r/redhat/ubi8) base image.